# I can't access port externally. What can I do?

Tags: iptables, firewall, ip

(Ubuntu 20.04)

I have ufw disabled, and I can't seem to access my game server externally with the public IP and port (1848). I can however, connect locally, just not externally.

When I run: netstat -tulnp | grep 1848

I get:

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1848            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      26145/wineserver

Question: What can I try that may get port 1848 accessible externally?

Comment: Have you forwarded the port across your router?

Comment: I'm using a cloud server with Ionos by 1&1. I don't think I have router access..

Comment: Ah... in that case I have no idea - sorry

Comment: You might have to contact the cloud server provider and see if they can forward that port for you.

Comment: Buffoon here. It turns out that they have a Firewall Policies section I didn't see. Now it works. I'd up vote your comments but I can't being new. :(